# PHP move_uploaded_file to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having difficulty with the code.  I am trying to upload the file to the server folder and insert in to SQL BLOB.  Neither one of it works.  Any suggestions?

```
<?php mysql_connect ("host","user","pass") 
    mysql_select_db("pics") 

    $image= addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
    $name= addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $image= file_get_contents($image); 
    $image= base64_encode($image); 

    if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "http://www.website.com/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])) { 
    $insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO pics (name,file) values ('$name','$image')"); 
    } 
    else "error uploading query to database"; 

    ?>
```

Comment: AFAIK the path passed to `move_uploaded_file` mustn't be an url. Do you receive an error? Which one? Even though files are not stored in db, will they be uploaded to server at least? ***mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo***

Comment: @AMartinNo1 you're correct.  it wasn't uploading to the folder but once i changed it to just uploads/ the image does upload to server.  now only if i could upload it to the db

Comment: 2 things, 1st is try to move on mysqli instead of mysql. 2nd is that check error log

Answer (score 0):

First of all (agree with @AMartinNo1) don't use mysql functions, use PDO.

Also (one more time agree with @AMartinNo1) 2nd parameter to `move_uploaded_file` must be path to file on your server (file system path).

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=pics;host=host', 'user', 'pass');

$image = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
$name = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']); 
$image = file_get_contents($image); 
$image = base64_encode($image);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/tmp/myUploadedFile')) {
    $s = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO pics (name, file) VALUES (:name, :file)');
    $s->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $s->bindValue(':file', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if (!$s->execute()) {
        throw new Exception($s->errorInfo());
    }
}
```